# yajra/laravel-datatables package - Class DataTablesServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I'm working on a project using Laravel as a framework.
After creating all the migrations I need to use, I would like to begin with the implementation of the CRUD operation. Using the InfyOm library, with a few commands I can pull out a layout for my backoffice.
The problem is, however, the use of the yajra library for the creation of datatables.
Following GitHub's Guide, I'm coming to update my Composer and the latter gives me this type of error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider' not found
```

In `Composer.json` I have the following data:

```
    ...
    "php": "> = 5.6.30",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4. *"
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~ 6.0"
    ...
```

While in `config/app.php` I have:

```
'providers' =>
    ...,
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,


'aliases' => [
    ...,
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]
```

Can you tell me why I have this exception? I tried to change the version of PHP, yajra and even Laravel without getting results.

Comment: You still need to use the `use DataTables` keyword at the top

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the following command in the directory of your project?

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

[About the `dump-autoload` Composer command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

Comment: Try to run `composer update` then `composer install`

Comment: this is the result: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.

Comment: Okay and... What about the not-found DataTablesServiceProvider class?

Comment: I solved by updating the php verisone from 5 to 7. Then I had to manually add the app / datatables.php file (copying it from git) but when I go to create datatables in the browser i have this error "
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'Yajra \ Datatables \ Services \ DataTable' not found
in BeaconDataTable.php (line 9) "